# "It is Germanys oldest pub." or "It is Germany's oldest pub."?

Tags: writing

The title says it all: I just want to know which of both are correct:

> (A) It is Germanys oldest pub.

or

> (B) It is Germany's oldest pub.

If you can give the rule, that would be nice. (I know that in some cases `'s` is only a shorthand for "is", like "it's" for "it is" whereas "its" refers to who something belongs to. But are all other cases without `'`? Are there differences in American English to British English?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to show *possession* is by adding *'s* (*apostrophe s*) to singular nouns.

(Pronouns *my*, *your*, *his*, *her*, ***its***, *their* have their own forms.)

So

> Germany's oldest pub

is the standard form and the form that learners need to learn.

Plural nouns that do not end in *s* work the same way:

> the **children's** oldest toys

Plural nouns that end in *s* get only an apostrophe added:

> the two **boys'** newest room

---

Reasons you might see possession without the apostrophe include:

1 contexts where standard punctuation is bypassed, such as in texting or other  highly informal or stylized contexts.

2 writers who choose not to use it because they feel it is unnecessary. These writers are deliberately going against the "rule" or standard usage.

However, these are special exceptions.

Comment: @GoDucks- **Off topic:** Are you a fellow alum of the U of O? Just curious.  1977 for me.

Comment: @MarkHubbard No, sorry, just an Anaheim Ducks (NHL) fan. Are you any relation to L. Ron Hubbard?

Comment: Hahahahaha! 45 years ago I was asked that a lot, but no, no relation!

Comment: You allude to this, but I think it merits further explanation: The possessive *its* (as in, "We saw a deer it the woods; its leg appeared to be broken") does *not* take an apostrophe and therefore is less likely to be confused with the contraction *it's* (meaning "it is"). (Words like *my* and *her* seem to get confused less often than *its*, probably because of the common contraction.)

Answer (score 1):

**"It is Germany's oldest pub,"** is correct. The apostrophe followed by an "s" confers possession. For many words that already end in "s" (or are plural), an apostrophe alone is sometimes enough. For instance, **"I just sold my parents' home this past week."** If you do a search on "use of apostrophes," I'm sure you will find many more examples.

Comment: Funny, though, we could also write: _It's Germany's oldest pub_, but those two apostrophes would be used for two different purposes: the first for the contraction, the second for the possessive form.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is

> It is **Germany's** oldest pub

Since it is **possessive**, it is not a contraction.

In terms of grammar, there is no difference between AmE and BrE.

However, the difference between AmE and BrE is that traditionally, Americans do not have **pubs**, they have **bars** or **saloons**(Western cowboys).  The British have **pubs**. They are demarcated by **hanging flower baskets** on the front outside wall, have **wooden interiors**, and **a very regular clientele**. BrE has the phrases **pub culture** and **pub grub**(food).

[NB: To refer to Germany's oldest **pub** would be a reference to a **non-German(origin) drinking house**, i.e. Irish pub, or possibly a non-German referring to a ***gaustehaus***.  ***Gaustehaus*** is more like a British *free house* which includes accommodations ]